# Disable a textbox using CSS

Tags: css, textbox

How to disable a textbox in CSS?
Currently we are having a textbox in our view which can be enabled/disabled depending on a property in the model.
We are having asp.net MVC view; depending on the value of the Model property we need to either render a textbox or readonly textbox.
we were thinking of doing this by applying CSS to the view control.
Has someone done this earlier?

Comment: Note that there's a subtle difference between `readonly` and `disabled`. In both cases the value is uneditable, but the former will send the value to the server side anyway, while the later won't. Also the later has in most webbrowsers a different (darker/grayed out) default style.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

CSS cannot disable the textbox, you can however turn off display or visibility.

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

Or you can also set the HTMLattribute:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

Answer (score 82):

you can disable via css:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Doesn't work everywhere though.

Comment: Text input can still be tabbed into.

Comment: `pointer-events: none` isn't supported by IE 8, 9, is for SVG elements only in 10, and is finally supported in 11, according to posts in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Comment: Thanks! Another tip would be to add some background-color to change visually and help the user see the difference when u don't have control over the html

Answer (score 56):

You can't disable anything with CSS, that's a functional-issue. CSS is meant for design-issues. You could give the impression of a textbox being disabled, by setting washed-out colors on it.

To *actually* disable the element, you should use the disabled boolean attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="lname" disabled />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p6rja/

Or, if you like, you can set this via JavaScript:

```
document.forms['formName']['inputName'].disabled = true;​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/655Su/

Keep in mind that disabled inputs won't pass their values through when you post data back to the server. If you want to hold the data, but disallow to directly edit it, you may be interested in setting it to `readonly` instead.

```
// Similar to <input value="Read-only" readonly>
document.forms['formName']['inputName'].readOnly = true;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/655Su/1/

This doesn't change the UI of the element, so you would need to do that yourself:

```css
input[readonly] { 
    background: #CCC; 
    color: #333; 
    border: 1px solid #666 
}
```

You could also target any disabled element:

```css
input[disabled] { /* styles */ }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't disable a textbox in CSS. Disabling it is not a presentational task, you will have to do this in the HTML markup using the `disabled` attribute.

You may be able to put something together by putting the textbox underneath an absolutely positioned transparent element with z-index... But that's just silly, plus you would need a second HTML element anyway.

You can, however, *style* disabled text boxes (if that's what you mean) in CSS using

```
input[disabled] { ... }
```

from IE7 upwards and in all other major browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Going further on Pekka's answer, I had a style "style1" on some of my textboxes. You can create a "style1[disabled]" so you style only the disabled textboxes using "style1" style:

```
.style1[disabled] { ... }
```

Worked ok on IE8.

Comment: `style1` is a terrible class name. Was it generated by a tool?

Comment: @alex Haha no, the name is a kind of awkward pt-br string so I used "style1".

Answer (score 2):

**&tl;dr**:  No, you can't disable a textbox using CSS.

`pointer-events: none` works but on IE the CSS property only works with IE 11 or higher, so it doesn't work everywhere on every browser. Except for that you cannot disable a textbox using CSS.

However you could disable a textbox in HTML like this:

```html
<input value="...." readonly />
```

But if the textbox is in a form and you want the value of the textbox to be not submitted, instead do this:

```html
<input value="...." disabled />
```

So the difference between these two options for disabling a textbox is that `disabled` cannot allow you to submit the value of the `input` textbox but `readonly` does allow.

For more information on the difference between these two, see ["What is the difference between `disabled="disabled"` and `readonly="readonly"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht/7730719#7730719).

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" onkeypress="javascript:return false;" width="50px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This won't allow any characters to be entered inside the TextBox.

Comment: Careful with this. Users could still right click and choose paste from the context menu to paste data into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

**just copy paste this code and run you can see the textbox disabled  **

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title> 

<style>.container{float:left;width:200px;height:25px;position:relative;}
       .container input{float:left;width:200px;height:25px;}
       .overlay{display:block;width:208px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:32px;} 
</style>
 </head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
       <input type="text" value="rvi.tom@gmail.com" />
       <div class="overlay">
        </div>
       </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Code without explanation is generally a bad answer on Stack** Anyway, this does very little for a whole lot of code. It only gives the appearance of being disabled and in a rather messy way. If a developer accepts this as valid, they could just as easily use a `input.disabled` and add the class via javascript as needed. You could also use an event handler on `focus` to `blur`. Solutions which easily adapt to more than one element.

Answer (score -2):

Another way is by making it readonly:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDis" readonly />
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it is helpful to explain what new aspects your answer brings, and to acknowledge if the passage of time impacts the answer.

Comment: And to include code blocks where appropriate. The only part of your answer I could see was "anotherway is by making it readonly".

Comment: Please explain what your answer truly means. "another way is by making it readonly" is very broad. This is not a real answer, this is a ***partial*** answer. Add more of this to make it complete.

Comment: Can a question like this be removed? No offence to silentwarrior, but in this situation there is plenty of other "higher quality" answers which should take this one's place.