# How do I make a text input non-editable?

Tags: html, css, html-input

So I have a text input

```
<input type="text" value="3" class="field left">
```

Here is my CSS for it

```
background:url("images/number-bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border:0 none;
color:#FFFFFF;
height:17px;
margin:0 13px 0 0;
text-align:center;
width:17px;
```

Is there a setting or a trick to this, I was thinking of doing a label instead but how about the styling. How do I convert them and is there a better way or is that the only way?

Answer (score 787, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="3" class="field left" readonly>
```

No styling necessary.

See `<input>` on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes

Comment: or readonly="readonly" if you like it being all XML-y, see Stephan Muller's example below :)

Comment: @Algy Taylor: Yeah, that was in the original answer when the original question had a wayward [xhtml] tag that drove everyone nuts about which was valid for which standard :/

Comment: is there any way to remove that red circle that comes up when you hover over `textarea` with `readonly` attribute?

Comment: Is it possible to I do that for a part of text in the `textarea`? (not whole of text)

Comment: @Shafizadeh - No, and that is a good thing. Would be difficult for browsers to implement correctly, and confusing for people to understand. don't try to make a simple control do a complex task. Break your input into pieces, with each piece simple (an editable control, then a non-editable HTML element, then another editable control).

Comment: Can you update this input field with javascript? And if yes, how? Can I simply get it by name and edit it's .value?

Comment: Also make sure to check this server side if you don't want the value to be persisted. It is easy in the browser's developer tool to remove the attribute, which on its turn makes the input field again editable.

Comment: Yup... always validate your input. Always validate your input. Oh and before I forget: always validate your input.

Comment: if you want to style it: use the attribute selector. Example: `input[readonly] { background-color: lightgray; }`

Answer (score 75):

You can add the attribute `readonly` to the input:

```
<input type="text" value="3"
       class="field left" readonly="readonly">
```

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: readonly not work with hidden input

Answer (score 45):

You can use `readonly` attribute, if you want your input only to be read. And you can use `disabled` attribute, if you want input to be shown, but totally disabled (even processing languages like PHP wont be able to read those).

Comment: When you send form to a php file, it won't read disabled inputs. It may be what he meant.

Comment: what acctualy happens is that disabled inputs are NOT EVEN SENT when you submit a form, has nothing to do with php, js or anything.

Answer (score 30):

Just to complete the answers available:

An input element can be either readonly or disabled (none of them is editable, but there are a couple of differences: focus,...)

Good explanation can be found here:
[What's the difference between disabled=“disabled” and readonly=“readonly” for HTML form input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/814702)

How to use:

```
<input type="text" value="Example" disabled /> 
<input type="text" value="Example" readonly />
```

There are also some solutions to make it through CSS or JavaScript as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458595/disable-a-textbox-using-css).

Comment: If you are going to use `/>` to close your tags, you may as well expand your attributes to `disabled="disabled"` and `readonly="readonly"` too.

Answer (score 12):

if you really want to use **CSS**, use following property which will make field non-editable.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `readonly`:

```
<input type="text" value="3" class="field left" readonly>
```

If you want the value to be not submitted in a form, instead add the `disabled` attribute.

```
<input type="text" value="3" class="field left" disabled>
```

There is no way to use CSS that always works to do this.

Why? CSS can't "disable" anything. You can still turn off display or visibility and use `pointer-events: none` but `pointer-events` doesn't work on versions of IE that came out earlier than IE 11.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" value="3" class="field left" readonly>
```

You could see  in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

The method to set "readonly":

```
$("input").attr("readonly", true)
```

to cancel "readonly"(work in jQuery):

```
$("input").attr("readonly", false)
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add **disabled** at the end

```
<input type="text" value="3" class="field left" disabled>
```

Comment: The value is not submitted if you set it to disabled.  It might be what *you* need, but it's not what was asked.  *As a side note, I came here precisely because my "disabled" input wasn't behaving like I was expecting*

Answer (score 0):

every input must have readonly or editable field so use it

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` and `disabled` will work. But if you want to send input value, just use `readonly` and edit your css .field left:focus{ outline: none }

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you just want to make the input element non-editable or unchangeable, which means the text cursor can still be placed there and the cursor can be moved around but only the text remains unchanged. It differs from readOnly or disabled.

1. Pure JS([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23qwkryn/11/))

```js
document.getElementById('input')
  .addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  var field = e.target;
  var oldValue = field.value;
  setTimeout(function () {
    if(field.value !== oldValue) {
      field.value = oldValue;
    } 
  }, 1);
  })
```

```html
<input id="input", type="text" value="default" class="field left">
```

2. use JQuery([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23qwkryn/5/))

```
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
var oldValue=$(this).val();
var field=this;
setTimeout(function () {
    if(field.value !== oldValue) {
        $(field).val(oldValue);
    } 
}, 1);
});
```

```
<input id="input", type="text" value="default" class="field left">
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for React then you may try:

```js
<input type="text" value="John" readOnly={true}/>
```