# How can I make a text input non editable with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

I searched for this and the closest thing I found was this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676127/how-do-i-make-a-text-input-non-editable/3676132); however, it does not use React.

I tried this syntax below which is inside a React component:

```
  <input 
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.onChange} 
    className={props.className}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    name={props.name} {props.readonly && 'readonly'}>
```

but I get an eslint parsing error and when I check the UI it is still writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you used is non-normative.

Instead of using

```
 ... readonly>
```

use the more common HTML syntax as follows:

```
readonly='readonly'
```

and then pick one of the many ways to implement in react / JSX.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `{props.readonly && 'readonly'}`
and add `readonly={props.readonly}` Refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-readonly) for the readonly attribute description.

Your problem is the input element (and all react components) only takes key/value pairs in the form of key={value}, but you are trying to insert a bit of javascript code without assigning the value of the result to a key.

Edit: should use readonly attribute, not disabled, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Assuming `props.readonly` is a boolean

Comment: interesting ... will try this too and see how it works ... your profile pic is broken btw.

Comment: looks like they are comparing to 'readonly'....if not a bool use `disabled={props.readonly == 'readonly'}`

Comment: disabled won't allow it to be submitted in a form whereas readonly will. They are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Use the property `readOnly` and pass it a boolean

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  return (    
      <input readOnly={props.readonly} value={props.title}/>   
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" readonly={true}/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
[readonly] {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This is amazing how many solutions there are.  This one appears the easiest and most consistent with the rest of my code.  I'm surprised this was not the solution to the original link I posted.  It seems more "standard" or "normalized".

Answer (score 1):

You could have an `input` without the `onChange` when `props.readonly` is `true`.
Something like this:

```js
<input 
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.readonly ? undefined : props.onChange} 
    className={props.className}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    name={props.name}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah a clear div could block from clicking on it, but user could still tab into it. You could also not let user tab into it, but that sometimes wouldn't be a great user experience.