# Javascript keypress event not functioning in Firefox. What is the alternative?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I tried to create an date type input field that would not take key value from keyboard. I used

```
<input type="date" (keypress)="false"/>
```

This **keypress event** working on Chrome browser

## but **not working on Mozilla Firefox**.

I tried to create an date type input field that would not take key value. I used

```
<input type="date" (keypress)="false"/>
```

This is working on Chrome browser

## but ** keypress event not working on Mozilla Firefox**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a text input non-editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676127/how-do-i-make-a-text-input-non-editable)

Comment: And why? That's bad UX.

Comment: What about use `keydown` or `keyup`? ([keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) is deprecated)

Comment: I agree `keydown`/`keyup` could be a replacement for `keypress` but I would suggest `input` event instead as long as you don't need to `preventDefault()` any keyDown in case they don't match a condition.

Comment: I tried all this, but not working!!

Answer (score -2):

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Please provide some details in your answer