# Disable a text box without using disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

Is there a simple Javascript or JQuery way to make a textbox disabled WITHOUT using the attribute disabled?

We are using Handlebar.js and when a disabled field is found it skips the field when its serialized so we can't use the disabled attribute. Is there a way to make the textbox uneditable still? Perhaps with a focus or blur?

Comment: Can you use Readonly?

Comment: I'll test readonly now. Thanks

Comment: Read more about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458595/disable-a-textbox-using-css

Comment: The link isn't what was asked

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `readonly` attribute instead :

```
$('#textBox').prop('readonly', true);
```

*Use .attr() instead of .prop() if you're using jQuery < 1.9*

Comment: Of course ! As `disabled`, it's part of [HTML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12).

Comment: Yeah just double checking you know IE

Answer (score 5):

directly add "readonly" attribute to the input element like this

```html
Name: <input type="text" value="editing me is disabled" readonly>
```

It works like charm. No need of using jquery for that.

Comment: this is what i wanted, Thank you @Ashish Gaikwad

Answer (score 1):

```
document.forms['formName']['inputName'].readOnly = true;
```